# Create a 301 redirect in nginx using easyengine

Tags: nginx, http-redirect

> I installed easyengine (https://rtcamp.com/easyengine/) on my local machine. I can login to it using ssh www-data@localhost command
>
> I created a site ankit.com
>
> I want to prevent direct download of http://ankit.com/wp-content/uploads/test.zip, for the same I want to create a 301 redirect to homepage of the site ankit.com
>
> I tried to modify the file at /etc/nginx/sites-available/ankit.com, but unfortunately owner of that file is 'root' and I don't know what is password of 'root' user.

Can you please let me know how I can create 301 redirect so that zip file will not be accessible directly?

Thanks for help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are planning to achieve.

You can use add a location block `deny` access from outside world.

Something like below:

```
location /wp-content/uploads {
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    deny all;
}
```

Then have a php script serve download after some sort of token verification. PHP can read file as it will be local access.